# If I add new rows to existing rows in datagridview, how to insert only this new rows to sql database in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview, sql-update

I would like to know when I load data to datagridview to update them, after add new rows to existing rows,how can I update newly added rows without duplication of existing rows. Here my code

```
 private void btnedit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
        try
        {
            if (txtPONo.Text != "" || cmbsupID.Text != "" || date1.Text != "" || requireddate.Text != "" || txtgrandTotal.Text != "")
            {
                PurchaseOrder PO = new PurchaseOrder();
                if (cmbsupID.Text.Contains('-'))
                {
                    string str = cmbsupID.Text;
                    int index = str.IndexOf('-');
                    if (index > 0)
                    {
                        int value = int.Parse(str.Substring(0, index));
                        PO.UpdatePurchseOrderTable(Convert.ToInt32(txtPONo.Text), value, date1.Text, requireddate.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtgrandTotal.Text));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(cmbsupID.Text);
                    PO.UpdatePurchseOrderTable(Convert.ToInt32(txtPONo.Text), value2, date1.Text, requireddate.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtgrandTotal.Text));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    int PONO = Convert.ToInt32(txtPONo.Text);
                    string column1 = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    int column2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    double column3= Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    double column4 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                    PO.UpdatePOCartTable(PONO,column1,column2,column3,column4);

                }


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Provide Details!");
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            ClearData();
            retviewPO_No();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

additional-
In my program which has datagridview for insert,update or delete Purchase Order and it behave like as a shopping cart.This datagridview consist of BookName,ISBNNo,Order quantity,unit price and total.When I insert this datagridview data to database,each row insert with unique id PO_Cart_No(pk) which has identity value.

And also other background textbox details which are Po_No,supplier_Id and Grand total details insert into separate table which called PO table.And also this two tables link with foreign key PO_No.My question is when I add new row to existing row to update database,that new row didn't insert and only other row data has updated.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what the actual question is, but you should definitely check Entity Framework. It serves for CRUD operations.

Comment: Are you clear now?

Comment: Is it this cycle here where you want to avoid updates of existing rows?
 `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i++)`

Comment: From this cycle I could update only existing rows.But if I add new rows to existing rows.That newly added new rows didn't insert when I click update button.